# Life cycle confusion in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am calling a method  that populates a spinner from files in onCreate Method? As per the life cycle of andriod goes after it stops or if i use another apps it shouldnt populate spinner. however it is populating. Can you tell me why?

Comment: code and logcat trace please.

Comment: @abhi_is_learning_android do you need code for it.? First of all his question is not clear..

Comment: @roshan Welcome to SO your question should be clear

Comment: @Pragnani i know his question is not clear. maybe code of what he is trying to do will make his point more clear and help us understand his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it is populated in `onCreate()`, it will stay populated unless you quit the activity. If you use some other app or just press the home button the activity may not be destroyed. It might simply be in the `paused` state. Once you come back to your activity it will simply `resume` itself to the last state it was in i.e. the spinner will remain populated. Android might decide to kill activities in the paused state as well if memory is low.

If you want to quit the app, Press the back button while you are in the activity. Then the activity will probably be destroyed and when you open it again, `onCreate()` will be called and the spinner will be repopulated.

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt reply. So when do you think or doing what  i will not be able to populate the data?

Comment: Pressing the back-button will **not** "surely" destroy the application. That portion of your answer is simply incorrect.

Comment: @roshan If the populating code is in your onCreate(), then you will always be able to populate it whenever a new instance of your activity is created (unless there is an error in the populating code which doesn't seem to be the case here)

Comment: i am reading a file from SD card and populating it in spinner. i dont have any problem in doing that. i have define a spinner loading method in onCreate method. Sometimes i havent been able to load the spinner and i havent been abke to simmulate the problem.

Comment: has to do anything with the method being define in onCreate()??

Comment: As far as this question is concerned, my answer is sufficient. If there is any other problem you have related to loading the data, you should post it as another question so that others can help you.